# Is it possible to run an Ajax function inside an jqxhr.done function?

Tags: jquery, json, promise

```
var json = $.getJSON("sun.json", function(json1) {
    $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        //Json Code
    });
});
json.done(function() {
    $.getJSON("sun2.json", function(json1) {
        $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
            //More json Code
        });
    });
});
```

Would it be possible to do this? I want to generate some stuff with the first json file, then when it is done, do more stuff with the second json file. I don't see why it wouldn't work, but I figured I'd get some clarification here just in case.

Comment: Yes you can, but if you want to pass the data around from the second json call it would get more complex, then you have to return a promise which you can then pass out of the first json.done().

Comment: Please note that there is no such thing as a "json function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can execute `$.getJSON` inside the `.done` function.

That said, a good practice for chaining the `$.getJSON` calls (thanks to the [jquery promise interface](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)) would be to utilize the `then` function and might look something like this...

```
$.getJSON("sun.json", function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(key, data) {
        //do something
    });
})
.then(function() {
    return $.getJSON("sun2.json", function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(key, data) {
            //do something with sun2.json
        });
    });
})
.then(function() {
    return $.getJSON("sun3.json", function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(key, data) {
            //so something with sun3.json
        });
    });
});
```

Chaining the deferred promises like this prevents the ["callback pyramid of doom"](http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/1atmht/how_we_killed_the_callback_pyramid_of_doom/) allowing for a flatter and more readable code structure.

ADDENDUM
Thanks to @BenjaminGruenbaum for clearing up my earlier confusion!

Comment: I have no idea how this got accepted - `done` ignores return values, this also has the deferred anti pattern (explicit construction antipattern).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - thanks for the feedback, I'd welcome additional feedback on my edited answer if you'd care to comment further.

Comment: Your update won't work - you need to `return` from the `then`, getJSON already returns a promise. What you were doing is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Also, your first example would still not work since `done` ignores return values, so probably don't recommend it :) Anyway I've reverted the downvote.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Thanks.  And am I correct in thinking that by returning the `$.getJSON` from each `then` that this will now work as intended?

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks again @BenjaminGruenbaum.  I've edited my answer in full now.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to avoid the `$.getJSON` success callback (second argument) altogether and *only* use `then`.